# How to model edited linked records of a multi-schema entity while preserving the original linked records?

Tags: database-design, design-pattern, data-versioning

If you have a base class `parent`. `parent` can have multiple `child` records, a one-to-many relationship.

```
parent schema:
+-----------+
| parent_id |
+-----------+

child schema:
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
```

Then `parent` is used in another entity, table `x`, that can have many `parent`s, again in a one-to-many relationship:

```
x_parent schema:
+------+-----------+
| x_id | parent_id |
+------+-----------+
```

Users can edit entities from table `x` to add and remove parents. While doing this, they can also edit the `child` records of the `parent`, however these changes need to be saved separately (as edits of `x`), not modifying the original `parent` or its `children`.

How should this be modeled to keep the data normalized, and also to know which records to use - the original `child` records, or some edited ones? This is the trickiest part to me, as the absence of edited records could mean the user removed all the original `child` records, or has simply not edited the `child` records of `parent`.

EG table `x_child` could look like this:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------+
| x_id | parent_id | child_edited_value |
+------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Is it a good idea to stick an `edited` column on the `x_parent` table, indicating to query for `x_child` rows instead of simply left joining `x_parent` with it's `child` records?

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the child_edited_value and just use a query instead to determine the place from which you want to fetch the data.

```
SELECT
    xp.x_id,
    xp.parent_id,
    c.child_id,
    CASE
        WHEN xc.child_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Edited'
        ELSE 'Original'
    END AS record_status
FROM
    x_parent xp
JOIN
    child c ON xp.parent_id = c.parent_id
LEFT JOIN
    x_child xc ON xp.x_id = xc.x_id AND xp.parent_id = xc.parent_id AND c.child_id = xc.child_id;
```

Comment: The problem here is that null does not mean necessarily to use the original. "as the absence of edited records could mean the user removed all the original child records, or has simply not edited the child records of parent"